# EditText setSelection clearing text then re-entering

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have been having issues with some odd behaviours from the EditText .setSelection that I am hoping you can all help with!

The app I am working on has a search field and there is the need to have it behave very similar to a browser search bar. For example, if the user types "fo", we would want the EditText to autocomplete to "foobar" with the autocompleted "obar" text highlighted so it can be easily replaced by the user incase the autocomplete does not match what the user was intending to type.

To accomplish this, I have an EditText field with a TextWatcher setup to try to autocomplete the text afterTextChanged. The following is my code:

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        int lastCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            String searchString = editable.toString();
            if (editable.length() > lastCount) {
                lastCount = editable.length();
                int oldLength = searchString.length();
                String autoFillResult = completeAutofill(searchString);
                if (!autoFillResult.equals("")) {
                    searchString = autoFillResult;
                    editable.clear();
                    editable.append(autoFillResult);
                    editText.setSelection(oldLength, autoFillResult.length());
                }

            } else lastCount = editable.length();

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
```

My issue is as follows. Using the previous "Foobar" case:

1. The user types "F", the EditText autofills "oobar" and highlights it.
2. Then the user types the first "o"
3. The EditText field is momentarily cleared (i.e. afterTextChanged receives an Editable with the empty string)
4. The EditText correctly autofills to user supplied "Fo" followed by autocompleted "obar" which is highlighted.

The issue is the EditText is being cleared then repopulated when the user types the next character, which creates a noticeable disturbance in the EditText field. Interestingly, I have singled out the                     editText.setSelection(oldLength, autoFillResult.length()); as the culprit (i.e. commenting out the line gets rid of the issue, but obviously its the wrong functionality).

After completing some Google research and my own debugging I am still unsure why this is happening. The issue does not appear excessively common as I could not find it on Google and I could not figure out the reason for this issue in my own experimentation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use autocompletetextview instead of edittext. I hope this will help you https://www.journaldev.com/9574/android-autocompletetextview-example-tutorial

Comment: @SurajGhadge I saw that functionality but it has a noticeably different look and feel. It offers options as a dropdown list underneath or above the EditText while I need to actually alter the text in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing  `editable.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

the `if` condition should possibly be:

```
autoFillResult != null && !autoFillResult.equals("")
```

while you might be looking for (or attempting to recreate) an [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView).

Comment: He removes the previous listener in the first line of afterTextChanged.

Comment: @BakonJarser that is correct, while I wonder if it even would be triggered when accessing the `EditText` alike that. the most common would be to call `super.afterTextChanged(editable)`, at first.

Comment: But I am removing the previous TextChangedListener? First line of afterTextChangedListener removes the listener and the last line puts the listener back in place. Without doing this, it goes into an infinite loop of making changes and listening to that change.

Comment: @dFrancisco you would have to de-bounce that functionality... adding/removing listeners might be correct in this case, but there should be a short delay added, in order not to instantly trigger the listener & the procedure.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Will give that a shot.